# Submeter formulario ao mudar checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Onde estou errando no meu formulario?
Ao mudar checkbox ele precisa submeter o formulario

HTML

```
<form id="form_onoff" name="form_onoff" action="onoff.php" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" value="on" id="slideThree" name="slideThree" />
<label for="slideThree"></label>
```

JQUERY

```
$(function($) {
$('input[type=checkbox][name=slideThree]').change(function() {
    $("#form_onoff").submit(function() {
        $.post('inc/onoff.php?id=<? echo $_SESSION['ids']; ?>', {slideThree: slideThree}, function(resposta) {
        });
    });
});
```

});

Obrigado desde já

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente verificar o status do *checkbox* dentro do evento `change()` dessa forma:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"][name="slideThree"]').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        // Aqui vai o $.post();
    }
});
```

Edit:

Notei agora que você está utilizando o `$.post`, ou seja, está realizando uma requisição **AJAX** dentro do seu *submit*. Acredito que não seja correto fazer assim.

Sugiro que você remova o `$("#form_onoff").submit()` do seu *jQuery*.

Comment: Então. Coloquei o post da forma q estava mesmo. Ae quando clico ele da um travada e fica um tempo pensando :(

Comment: Se você utilizar somente o `$.post()` pela lógica deve funcionar. :)

Comment: Funcionou. Linha do post estava errada. Brigadão

Comment: Precisando, estamos aí! :D

Answer (score 1):

```
Experimente assim:

$('input[type=checkbox][name=slideThree]').on('click', function() {
  $("#form_onoff").attr("action", "inc/onoff.php?id=<? echo $_SESSION['ids']; ?>");
  $("#form_onoff").submit();
});
```

Comment: Então, mas acho que sem a função post ele vai mudar de página não vai?